# Then appears to fire before async returns value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting an error almost like my .then is firing before my async call is finished. I realize I am looping for the api post, but i am currently only trying it with an array size of 1.

Service:

```
this.saveTags = function (tag) {
        $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: '/api/projects/' + data.Id + '/tags',
            data: ({ Name: tag.Name })
        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response.data)
            if (typeof response.data === 'object') {
                return response.data;
            } else {
                // invalid response
                return $q.reject(response.data);
            }
        }, function (response) {
            // something went wrong
            return $q.reject(response.data);
        });
```

Controller:

```
 tags.forEach(function(tag) {
            counter++;
            data.saveTags(tag).then(function(data) {
                console.log(data)
            });
        });
```

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a promise from the function that is resolved or rejected when the `$http` POST request is finished.

It looks like instead you're trying to return the `reject` and `resolve` products from the `$http` function itself, while your `saveTags` function ends up returning nothing to its caller (ie. from your `forEach` loop).

Try this:

```
this.saveTags = function (tag) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: '/api/projects/' + data.Id + '/tags',
        data: ({ Name: tag.Name })
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data)
        if (typeof response.data === 'object') {
            deferred.resolve(response.data);
        } else {
            // invalid response
            deferred.reject(response.data)
        }
    }, function (response) {
        // something went wrong
        deferred.reject(response.data)
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: I think the problem may come from data.saveTags(tag).then(function()) not returning anything

Comment: Also, I've had better experience when I assign the result of $http to a variable and use variable.then(...);. Other than that, this is very well structured and a good answer.

Comment: @allencoded Not sure of what you mean. The error you reported is showing that you're trying to call `then` on undefined. Your `saveTags` function is not returning an object with a `then` method. If you return deferred.promise, even if your $http call doesn't return results, you'll still return something with a `then` method, which will prevent the error.

Comment: Have any luck fixing this?